# Passing session to a PHP script called by the VLC plugin

Tags: php, session, vlc, session-state

I have a website with IP camera recordings - users can log in and see them. I'm using VLC to display them on the website:

```
$(this).closest(".recording_wrapper").find(".recording_preview").append(
    '<div class="embed_vlc_wrapper">' +
        '<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"' +
            'version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"' +
            'target="../PHP/get_recording.php?file=' + $(this).closest(".recording_wrapper").attr("file") + '&camid=' + $(this).closest(".recording_wrapper").attr("camera_id") + '"' +
            'pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"' +
        '/>' +
    '</div>'
);
```

When the above code is loaded, the user is already logged in and all session variables are set. Unfortunately `get_recording.php` doesn't recognise the existing session and tries to create a new one upon calling the `session_start()` function. So for example if I would add this code to my webpage:

```
/* That's inline PHP code on my website, the session is already started */
error_log(session_id());
```

And this code to the `get_recording.php` script:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
   session_start();
}
error_log(session_id());
```

I would get different session IDs. How can I solve this problem? I need to somehow pass the session id from my webpage to the `get_recording.php` script without showing it to the user (i.e. including it in the target URL).
I thought about uploading it to a MySQL database upon login, then downloading it in the `get_recording.php` script, but I realised that it's pointless - I still need to compare it to an existing session id which this script doesn't know.
I also read about passing it in a cookie, but is it even possible in this situation? Can VLC plugin pass a cookie to another script?

Comment: check where You can get session variable

Comment: @KarthiVenture what do you mean? I can get the $_SESSION variable at every point in my code across all PHP scripts. It is passed automatically between these scripts upon calling the `session_start()` function - that's how the session ID is propagated. The problem is that the `get_recording.php` script doesn't use the existing session like all other scripts do.